# How to config for WebSocket on Linux CentOS 7(Apache)?

Tags: node.js, linux, apache, websocket, centos

I am developing node application for WebRTC.
Currently I am using socket.io for real time communication.
But I have following error when connect to signaling server placed on Linux CentOS7(Apache).

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=BmT1OlWRijuoGNpXAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing

I am using socket.io.js in client side.

```
<script src = "/javascripts/lib/socket.io.js"></script>
```

`<script type = "javascript"> 
    var socket = io();
</script>`

I think this is happened cause of my websocket config in httpd.conf.
Would you like to help me?

Comment: use nginx as a reverse proxy, it's a lot simpler than Apache, and follow this config : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506050/socket-io-nginx-configuration-error-during-websocket-handshake-connection-hea