# Angular.js + Socket.io image rendering issue with iOS7 / Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, safari, socket.io

I'm running a web app with Angular.js (ver. 1.2.21) and Socket.io for a simple image-based chatting. (click an image and the image link is sent to others in the chat room). The messages are added to a $scope.messages and looped with:

```
   <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <p>{{message.user}}</p> 
    <p ng-bind-html="message.text | unsafe"></p>
    <p>{{message.time}}</p> 
    <hr>
  </div>
```

Where `{{message.text}}` is something like `"<img src='/img/test.png'>"`

To render the images in Angular, I added "unsafe" sanitize filter to `{{message.text}}` :

```
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
})
```

The images load very fast on all devices (android, desktop), except for devices running Safari/iOS7 (iphone, ipad).

When a new chat by the user is added to the $scope.messages feed of chats (by pushing to end of $scope.messages array), it doesn't display the sanitized `<img>` (it's blank) but does show the other message information `{{message.user}}` and `{{message.time}}` in the feed.

After around 10 seconds the sanitized `<img>` might load on the device, but not always.

If there are incoming chats from other devices, then all of the un-rendered images suddenly display properly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the problem. nginx needed to be upgraded to 1.4.4

More information on what exactly to do is here:
http://www.slashgeek.net/2013/05/08/how-to-get-the-latest-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04-2-lts-precise-pangolin/

And here:
[WebSocket connection failed with nginx, nodejs and socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718245/websocket-connection-failed-with-nginx-nodejs-and-socket-io)